# Versionless XSDs are not available

Tags: spring, xsd

We have an app that used to work fine before last weekend, when we started getting these errors:
[org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] - 
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
 at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 ...
It looks like versionless XSDs are not available anymore (e.g. http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd). Since we didn't change anything in our app, could it be due to the release of new 4.1 RC?

Comment: RC isn't final it is a Release Candidate in general it is better to wait until it is final, at least for production usage.

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is that we're using versionless schemas, and they are NOT available at all! It just gives you 404 http error, so the *xsd. files cannot be found.

Comment: They shouldn't even be resolved from the internet they should be resolved from the spring jar files. Make sure that you don't mix versions of different spring jars.

Answer (score 0):

Like you suspected, this is indeed a glitch in the release process of 4.1 RC1 last Friday. These files will be restored shortly and you can follow-up on the actual issue at [SPR-12011](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12011)

That being said, @m-deinum is right, these files should be resolved locally from the spring jars.